# Cannot convert type 'string' to 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument'?

Tags: c#, .net, html-agility-pack

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace sss
{
    public class Downloader
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();

        public HtmlDocument FindMovie(string Title)
        { 
            //This will be implemented later on, it will search movie.
        }

        public HtmlDocument FindKnownMovie(string ID)
        {
            HtmlDocument Page = (HtmlDocument)client.DownloadString(String.Format("http://www.imdb.com/title/{0}/", ID));
        }
    }
}
```

How can I convert a downloaded string to a valid HtmlDocument so I can parse it using HTMLAgilityPack?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work with v1.4:

```
HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load(string.Format("http://www.imdb.com/title/{0}/", ID));
```

or

```
string html = client.DownloadString(String.Format("http://www.imdb.com/title/{0}/", ID));
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this (based on [this fairly old document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/joshch/better-html-parsing-and-validation-with-htmlagilitypack)):

```
string url = String.Format("http://www.imdb.com/title/{0}/", ID);
string content = client.DownloadString(url);
HtmlDocument page = new HtmlDocument();
page.LoadHtml(content);
```

Basically casting is *rarely* the right way of converting between two types - particularly when there's something like parsing going on.

Answer (score 1):

The following lines of code will create a `HtmlDocument` with your content:

```
// First create a blank document
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
// Then load it with the content from the webpage you are trying to parse
doc.Load(new StreamReader(WebRequest.Create("yourURL").GetResponse()
                                 .GetResponseStream()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could create a new file (.html) in for file system and then use a stream writer to write the string into the html file. Then pass that file to the parser